# Retrieve more photos from instagram api on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, instagram

I am building a basic app that retrieves Instagram pics from a certain `tag name`. I am using the [instagram-api-php](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) repo. So far so good. I run into a problem trying to load more pictures related to that `tag name`. I am using `next_max_id` as described in the [instagram api pagination](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/). I have placed a `button` in the page and assigned `next_max_id` to load the rest of the photos. But no photos are being loaded. How could I load more photos on button click? I follow the example from [Github](https://gist.github.com/cosenary/2959827)

index.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#more').click(function() {
        var tag   = $(this).data('tag'),
            maxid = $(this).data('maxid');

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data: {
            tag: tag,
            max_id: maxid
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            // Output data
            $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
              $('ul#photos').append('<li><img src="' + src + '"></li>');
            });

            // Store new maxid
            $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

<?php
  /**
   * Instagram PHP API
   */

    require_once 'Instagram.php';


    // Initialize class with client_id
    // Register at http://instagram.com/developer/ and replace client_id with your own
    $instagram = new Instagram('API KEY');

    // $geo = $instagram->searchMedia(56.8770413, 14.8092744);

    $tag = 'sweden';

    // Get recently tagged media
    $media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag);

    // Display first results in a <ul>
    echo '<ul id="photos">';

    foreach ($media->data as $data) 
    {
        echo '<li><img src="'.$data->images->thumbnail->url.'"></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    // Show 'load more' button
    echo '<br><button id="more" name="max_id" data-maxid="'.$media->pagination->next_max_id.'" data-tag="'.$tag.'">Load more ...</button>';
?>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * Instagram PHP API
     */
      set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
      require_once 'Instagram.php';
      use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;

      // Initialize class for public requests
      $instagram = new Instagram('API KEY');

      // Receive AJAX request and create call object
      $tag = $_GET['tag'];
      $maxID = $_GET['max_id'];
      $clientID = $instagram->getApiKey();

      $call = new stdClass();
      $call->pagination->next_max_id = $maxID;
      $call->pagination->next_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{$tag}/media/recent?client_id={$clientID}&max_tag_id={$maxID}";

      // Receive new data
      $media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag,$auth=false,array('max_tag_id'=>$maxID));

      // Collect everything for json output
      $images = array();
      foreach ($media->data as $data) {
        $images[] = $data->images->thumbnail->url;
      }

      echo json_encode(array(
        'next_id' => $media->pagination->next_max_id,
        'images'  => $images
      ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
  $('ul#photos').append('<li><img src="' + src + '"></li>');
});
```

to

```
$.each(data.images, function(i, img) {
  $('ul#photos').append('<li><img src="' + img.standard_resolution.url + '"></li>');
});
```

Not 100% certain that is the correct property name, but as it stands, you're looping through an array of image objects, setting each image object to `src`, then trying to use `src` as the image source, when in fact it's the image object. `src` is likely a property of it.

**EDIT**: Here's a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/vuvuda/1/edit?js,output) demo. If `data.images` is in fact an array of objects, my solution should work...

Comment: Well, what happens when you `console.log(img)` ? (or whatever you're setting it to.

Comment: @techAddict82 See my edit. This all assumes you're actually getting back data. What happens when you console log before the append?

Comment: One sec, I am trying to get this on demo site. Yes i am getting data back.

Comment: Oh sorry my webserver doesnt support `cURL` so i wont be able. I tried `console.log(img)` but nohting shows. As mentioned in the console I am receiving a data back.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. You're saying you're getting data back, but when you log it, nothing shows. Either the function is not being executed at all, or you're not getting data back. Try `console.log('test'`) before the append and see if THAT shows.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, After page load in the console I am getting this response back `{"next_id":"1415742766179734","images":["http:\/\/scontent-b.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xpf1\/t51.2885-15]}`. But For `console.log('img')` nothing is showing up.